# How to change a SKIN in all pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, regex

I have a web project in which I use `Theme` and Skin to form my pages, today I decided to change some skins for some elements in my application.

Up to now I had a single skin for my buttons

```
<asp:Button SkinID="Button" CssClass="Button" runat="server" />
```

Now I want to change it for some of my buttons like

```
<asp:Button SkinID="SubmitButton" CssClass="Button Submit" runat="server" />
<asp:Button SkinID="DeleteButton" CssClass="Button Delete" runat="server" />
<asp:Button SkinID="CancelButton" CssClass="Button Cancel" runat="server" />
```

Allof my buttons implemented like

```
<asp:Button ID="btnDelete" SkinID="Button" runat="server" />
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" SkinID="Button" runat="server" />
<asp:Button ID="btnCancel" SkinID="Button" runat="server" />
<asp:Button ID="btnOtherActivities" SkinID="Button" runat="server" />
```

Now I want to use a regular expression  to change the SkinID of my controls to each equevalents

What Can I do?

Comment: Note that Using simple Replace is not my answer because I didn't use a single pattern for my buttons, for instance, Once I use `ID - runat - onClick - skin` and in another I used `ID - skin - runat - onClick `

Answer (score 0):

set up your theme inside your web.config file;

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <pages theme="ThemeName" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

if your can set up the same skinid names inside your new theme, those will be changed automatically.

Comment: I think Nasser is trying to change a bunch of SkinIDs (such as from SkinID="Button" to SkinID="Button Submit") inside a bunch of files.  This would need to be done in each control, not in a general theme.

Comment: @jdangelo I totally understood that :) my suggestion here is to configure a theme name globally and adding skins inside that theme whose id names are the same as there are now. so that he will be able to change the style without changing any other skinid. AFAIK, there is way to globally configure skinid for a control type, is there?

Comment: @tubberk I understand what you mean, now.  For some reason I read that as SkinName instead of ThemeName.  I don't think that will work, though, because if you have a bunch of the same type of control with the same SkinID, you can't add the granualar details like "Button Submit" since that would apply to all buttons, right?  So if you had three buttons on one page all with the SkinID="SomeIDName", you wouldn't have a way to specifiy which one gets the change.

Comment: @jdangelo if you want to change the SkinID of controls differently (for example change one button to **MySkin1** and the other to --**MySkin2**), there is no built-in way to change them in bulk.

Comment: @tugberk ya, and that's exactly what I think Nasser is trying to do.  Without affirmation, though, I suppose we're just shooting in the dark right now. (My apologies for mistyping your name in my previous comment. =D )

Comment: @jdangelo mistyping is not a problem :)